# An exhaustion of $C_b(\Omega)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions

Consider the space $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the space 
$C_b(\Omega)$ consisting of all bounded continuous functions 
defined in $\Omega$.

Actually we are considering in $C_b(\Omega)$ the sup norm.

**My Question:** It is  possible to  obtain 
a family $\{K_i\} \subset C_b(\Omega)$  of compact subsets with
$K_i\subset K_{i+1}$ for all $i$ s.t $\bigcup K_i=C_b(\Omega)$?

**My try:** I was thinking in the subsets $C_{b,i}(\Omega)$ of $C_b(\Omega)$
given by all continuous functions $f \in C_b(\Omega)$ s.t $f(x)=0$ if 
$x$ is outside $[-i,i]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

The set  $C_{b,i}(\Omega)$ is compact because $C_{b,i}(\Omega)$ is closed and 
$C_{b,i}(\Omega)$ is contained in $ \mathbb{R}^{[-i,i]^{\mathbb{N}}}\times \{0\}^{([-i,i]^{\mathbb{N}})^c}$ which is compact.

Is that correct?

If not, can you give an such exhaustion?

Comment: I don't understand how can the notation $\{K_i\} \subset \Omega$ can stay with $ \bigcup K_i=C_b(\Omega)$

Comment: There are lots of things I don't understand here. Please explain your notation!

Comment: The notation is currently corrected, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Each $K_i$ is separable, hence $\cup K_i$ is separable. But $C_b(\mathbb R^n)$ is nonseparable. To see the latter, think of a countable family of closed pairwise disjoint balls $B_m$ and continuous functions $f_m$ such that for every $m$: i)the support of $f_m$ is contained in $B_m;$ ii) $0\le f_m\le 1;$ iii) $f_m = 1$ somewhere in $B_m.$ For every binary sequence $(a_m)$ define the function

$$g_{(a_m)} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_mf_m.$$

Then each $g_{(a_m)} \in C_b.$ If $(a_m)\ne (b_m),$ then $\|g_{(a_n)}- g_{(b_n)}\|_\infty = 1.$ Since the set of binary sequences is uncountable, we see that $C_b(\mathbb R^n)$ is nonseparable.

Answer (score 1):

For any Banach space $X$, if there is an exhaustion $X=\bigcup_n K_n$ by compact sets, then one of the $K_n$ has an interior point by Baire's theorem.
This implies that $X$ is finite dimensional.